# How to pass header information of scrapy directly to splash

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I would like to login on splash based on the header information obtained by login authentication with scrapy.

I have two questions regarding this.

**question 1.**

Is it possible to pass header information obtained by logging in with scrpay directly to splash?

**question 2.**

Does it make sense with splash to recognize that it is not necessary to perform login authentication?

This is my base code.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

def test(self, response):
  self.logger.info("headers:-------"+ str(response.headers))
return SplashRequest(
       "url",
       self.test2,
       endpoint='execute',
       args={
       'lua_source': """Lua script""",
       'wait': 5,})
```

thank you for reading my question.

Comment: You can send headers with Splash, look at the [documentation](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-set-custom-headers).

Comment: @TomášLinhart  thank you for your advice.
Could you see because I made a new question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460009/after-logging-in-netflix-i-would-like-to-click-the-user-selection-button-made-w